# How to formally express a negative statement (in the wording or formulation of a theorem, for instance)

Tags: calculus, logic, proof-writing, article-writing

This is a doubt about English mathematical formal language.

I would like to know the best way to express a negative hypothesis, in the formulation or statement of a theorem, proposition, etc., using appropriate words, expressions, etc. This theorem is supposed to be included in a scientific paper.

Next, I show a concrete example.

I have proven a theorem. The theorem states that a certain function does not present a local minimum in a concrete part of its domain. This is the current phrasing:

> Consider [...] $f$ as a function of $x$, the rest of parameters being arbitrarily fixed. There does not
>   exist a value $x_{\min} \in \,]\,a, b\,[\,$ in which a (local) minimum
>   of $f$ is achieved, that is, verifying
>
> $$ \exists\, \epsilon > 0 \; \text{ such that } \; f(x_{\min}) \leq f(x) \quad \forall\, x \in \,]\,x_{\min} - \epsilon , x_{\min} + \epsilon\,[ \,\text{.} $$

The omitted part *"[...]"* stands for the meaning of $f$ (for instance: *"Consider the final height $f$ as a function of $x$."*). In my case, it makes sense the text *"as a function of $x$, the rest of parameters being arbitrarily fixed"* because the value of $f$ depends on several variables or parameters.

Is this writing or phrasing acceptable? Can it be improved? How?

---

EDIT:

I am asking this because, despite having checked out some calculus books written in English, it is difficult to find a negative statement in the thesis of a theorem, a proposition, etc., and I want to be sure that my theorem is well written before sending it to any scientific journal.

Comment: Looks good to me. One correction: "There does not exist a value ... **at** which ...". (You can check the preposition by reordering the sentence: $f$ would achieve a minimum *at* a given value, not *in* a given value.)

Comment: "Verifying" should read "satisfying" (these terms are not synonymous in English). Also putting a quantifier before and after a logical formula is ambiguous, does it mean $\forall x \in \ldots \exists x_{\mathrm{min}}$ or  $\exists x_{\mathrm{min}} \forall x \in \ldots$?

Comment: @RobArthan, I see what you mean. Would the ambiguity be solved by adding a colon like in: $\exists\, \epsilon > 0 \; \text{ such that: } \; f(\lambda_{\min}) \leq f(\lambda) \quad \forall\, \lambda \in \,]\lambda_{\min} - \epsilon , \lambda_{\min} + \epsilon[ \,$  ?  Thank you also for the remark about *"verifying"* vs *"satisfying"*.

Comment: @Théophile, thank you!

Comment: I don't think the colon helps very much. I would suggest putting the quantifiers on the same side of the formula (left or right - your choice, but logicians traditionally put them on the left).

Comment: @RobArthan, thank you again!! It helps a lot.